# why textView can't execute here

Tags: java, android, android-studio

in onPostExecute method textview at the end won't execute its stays in "hello world" not with json data
i initialize it in the top
tried to put it outside the for loop no doesn't help at all

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            pd.dismiss();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);
                for(int i = 0 ; i<array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String user = object.getString("username");
                    String address = object.getString("address");
                    JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject(address);
                    String city = object1.getString("city");
                    String geo = object1.getString("geo");
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(geo);
                    String lat = jsonObject.getString("let");
                    stringBuilder.append("username is " + user + " city is " + city + " let is " + lat + "\n");
                    textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Please include stacktrace if you're facing an error

Comment: i don't have an error for example textview in the oncreate hello in onPostExecute text won't change

Comment: I don't see you appending anything to the `stringBuilder`

Comment: stringBuilder.append("username is " + user + " city is " + city + " let is " + lat + "\n");

Comment: if you have a better idea to send the code it will be nice since there is limit here

Comment: i edited main Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asyncTask  class was deprecated in API level 30.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

i recommend you use this solution:

> Use the standard java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead.

```
ExecutorService exService  = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Handler handler=new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper);
exService.execute(new Runnnable(){
...
// your background works here 
//
//if you need change ui   use this:
handler.post(new Runnable(){
///change ui 
});

});
```

or if you want use AsyncTask use handler to run it on mainThread :

```
   new Hanndler(Looper.getMainLooper).post(new ...
    {
       textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
     });
```